# Laravel Valet: secure TLS certificate not working correctly on Ubuntu

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, valet

Am using laravel valet on ubuntu and it's working fine except for TLS part it was working but it stops suddenly. when I try to secure any one of my sites and open it on chrome I get this error
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4lytc.png)